# Module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'ximgproc'

Tags: python, opencv, opencv-contrib

I am trying to perform a selective search to an image using OpenCV but when I run my code I get this:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> ss = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createSelectiveSearchSegmentation()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'ximgproc'
```

I've seen similar problems but people solved them installing `opencv-contrib-python` package. I've already installed this module but the problem persists.

Here is my requirements file:

```
opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25
opencv-python==4.1.0.25
```

I am using a conda environment with python 3.7

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/

Comment: https://answers.opencv.org/question/125330/ximgproc-in-opencv2-file-not-found/

Comment: [How to install openCV for python 3.6 (64-bit) in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733847/176769) with **opencv_contrib**.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As mentioned in the OpenCV pypi web page:

1. If you have previous version of OpenCV installed remove it *before* installation to avoid conflicts.
2. There are 4 different `opencv` packages: `opencv-python`, `opencv-contrib-python`, `opencv-python-headless`, `opencv-contrib-python-headless`.
3. **You can only install one**. Multiple opencv packages are incompatible.

When asking my question, I had 2 opencv packages. Therefore I first removed the two existing packages:

```
$ pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python opencv-python
```

And then, I installed only one package:

```
$ pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Finally, the installation worked.

Comment: from the first step ".. OpenCV installed remove it *before* installation", emphasize on - before installation -

Answer (score 13):

This should solve the issue, if you have pip installed. I found pip installer to be better than conda installer in general.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade
```

works for me.