# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'nameWindow'

Tags: python, opencv

I've install opencv-python but it still have this problem.

python version:3.7.7

opencv-python version:4.4.0.46

opencv-contrib-python version:4.4.0.46

and here's my code

```
import cv2 as cv


def GetPicture():
    cv.namedWindow('camera', 1)
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv.imwrite('C:/person.jpg', frame)
    cap.release()
```

I've tried different version of opencv, this problem can't be solved.

Comment: Most likely some installation issue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427233/module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-ximgproc) for example.

Answer (score 0):

`nameWindow` doesn't exist. `namedWindow` does.

your code as you posted it could not have thrown that error.