# Error trying to install opencv-python on windows

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I entered

```
pip install opencv-python==4.2.0.32
```

and the command returned

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   opencv-python==4.2.0.32 (from versions: ) No matching distribution
>   found for opencv-python==4.2.0.32

I am using python 3.8.0 on Windows 10

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're using Python 3, then why are you still using the `pip` command? Try it with `pip3`

Comment: Can you run `python` in your cmd and then post the first line that is printed before `>>>` and also try `python-m pip install opencv-python==4.2.0.32` to make sure that the correct version is used?

Comment: [How to install OpenCV for Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733847/176769).

Comment: pip3 didn't work...gave same error

Answer (score 0):

May be there are no wheels for that release for your Python version because some of Python version did not exist back then

**Built Distributions**
Check here:
https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/4.2.0.32/#files

Answer (score -1):

To install do not enter the version of opencv.
Test it to see if it is installed!
Use the following command to install:

pip install -U opencv-python

I installed it easily. 
I updated it the same way

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem. You need to double check that your pip3 is in the path and that python knows it. 
To check it you need to go to the folder where your pip3.exe lives and try to run

```
pip3.exe install upgrade
```

if it doesn't work here is the dirty fix: 
you go to your python folder, where your python3 lives and try : `python3 ./Scripts/pip3.exe install  opencv-python==4.2.0.32`

The clean fix is to add pip3.exe to your path.

I suppose you specified your python folder as not a default one.

I hope you will figure out where your python lives and how to set the path to your pip3.exe

Comment: The difference is that you don't call pip3 directly, but you call it with python installed. Please read the suggested solution carefuly